# What is the default cookieAcceptPolicy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, foundation

I'm working on a iOS SDK that needs the `cookieAcceptPolicy` of the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` to be `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways` which should be the default according to the documentation:

> The default cookie accept policy is NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways. Changing the cookie policy affects all currently running applications using the cookie storage.

I've just created a new iOS project in XCode and this does not seem to be the case. The default policy is `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain`:

```
// this logs "cookieAcceptPolicy 2" (NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain)  
NSLog(@"cookieAcceptPolicy %@", @([NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy));
```

So the questions are

1. Why is the default cookieAcceptPolicy `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain` even if I did not change it?
2. Is the `sharedHTTPCookieStorage` shared across iOS applications?
3. Can the **user** of an application change the cookie accept policy via some iPhone settings?
4. What is the `cookieAcceptPolicy` of a `UIWebView` in a app?

cheers,
Jan

Comment: Not only that, but it seems that it's not even possible to change to anything else. :( I just created my own NSHTTPCookieStorage, and tried to change the policy to Always. No errors thrown but it's not changed.

Answer (score 2):

The docs are very misleading. You need to do this:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cs = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[cs setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

and it affects only your app's cookie storage, no other apps are affected.

Comment: So the default accept policy is *not* `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways ` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's `NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain` on 8.4. Not sure is this is influenced by some other settings I have setup on `NSURLSession` configuration.